# Lift-2.5 build issue in sbt/Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, lift

I'm trying to get a mac development environment operational around Eclipse, SBT and Lift. Once installed as near to proper as I'm able to manage, I can run the app from sbt, but Eclipse still reports problems.

- Eclipse is the Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK, Build id:
  3.0.1-vfinal-20130711-0941-Typesafe.
- SBT is macport installed: sbt @0.12.3_1
- Lift is the most recent 2.5 zip ([This](https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt/zipball/master) from [this page](http://liftweb.net/download).)

[This tutorial](http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/lift24scalaide20/index.html) was used for initial guidance. However, this tutorial is for a somewhat earlier version of Lift and associated dependencies, including the sbt-eclipse plugin. What I landed at was the 2.2 version of the eclipse plugin, and in my `~/.sbt/plugin/build.sbt` I have this single line:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.2.0")
```

Per the tutorial instructions, I'm pulling over the source file (of Lift's lift_basic project specifically) and modifying my project build.sbt to the following:

```
name := "sample project"

organization := "com.nford"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.Default + EclipseCreateSrc.Resource

libraryDependencies ++= {
        val liftVersion = "2.5"
        Seq(
                "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile",
                "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mapper" % liftVersion % "compile",
                "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.26" % "test",
                "junit" % "junit" % "4.7" % "test",
                "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "0.9.26",
                "org.scala-tools.testing" %% "specs" % "1.6.9" % "test",
                "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.2.147"
        )
}
```

Importing the project into Eclipse works fine, except for 20 errors, mostly around the test cases. These include, but are not limited to:

```
object eclipse is not a member of package org
not found: value JQueryModule
```

Googling errors like this I see a lot of stuff from a year ago, largely which seems to be a package mismatch. From this research I was able to make some changes (reflected in the build.sbt, etc. above):

- Upgrade scala version to 2.10.1
- Upgrade lift version to 2.5
- Use sbt-eclipse 2.2 plugin

Yet I'm still receiving these errors. To verify; I have updated, from the sbt terminal console, and run the eclipse build from there as well. I imported the project to Eclipse after that point. I am unable to determine where the package mismatches are coming from (or indeed why they can't be discovered, since they exist on the system and sbt can find them). Is this an eclipse IDE plugin weakness, or a solvable problem? Or, in my obvious newness to Scala Lift, am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQueryModule is not part of Lift. You need to add:

```
"net.liftmodules" %% "lift-jquery-module_2.5" % "2.3"
```

Jetty:

```
"org.eclipse.jetty"       %  "jetty-webapp"      % "8.1.7.v20120910"       %  "container,compile",
"org.eclipse.jetty"       % "jetty-servlets"     % "8.1.7.v20120910"       %  "container,compile",
"org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" %  "javax.servlet"     % "3.0.0.v201112011016"   %  "container,compile" artifacts Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar")
```

Specs2:

```
"org.specs2"              %% "specs2"            % "1.14"
```

Comment: That solved the jQuery errors beautifully! However, I'm at a loss how to track down what I need for, say, `org.specs2`, or `org.eclipse`, both of which are also not found. The latter has to do with jetty, which is why I'm particularly confused.

Comment: Managed to kick around until I found working versions. `org.mortbay` is deprecated. Thanks for the pointer!